# Laravel migration using migrations that dont exist

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying do to a very basic migration. When i run php artisan migrate i get this error:

```
Migrating: 2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'personal_access_tokens' already exists (SQL: create tab....///
```

As you can see, I dont have that "2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table" migration in my migrations table.

[image]

I have done the following:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
./composer dump-autoload
```

And im still getting this ghost migration.  What should i do?

The contents of the create_file_table file  I am trying to run is:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('quoteNumber');
        $table->string('purchaseOrderNumber');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('file_path')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: If you don't care about the existing data you could do `artisan migrate:fresh`.

Answer (score 21):

```
2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table
```

Is part of [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

You can publish it to your migrations folder by running the following command.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"
```

Otherwise it stays with the package and you will not see it in your migrations folder.

If you would like to ignore it you can follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#migration-customization) included below.

> ### [Migration Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#migration-customization)
>
> If you are not going to use Sanctum's default migrations, you should
> call the `Sanctum::ignoreMigrations` method in the `register` method
> of your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class. You may export the
> default migrations by executing the following command:
>
> `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=sanctum-migrations`

Comment: You can also remove Sanctum if you are not using it with `composer remove laravel/sanctum`

Comment: To add to @DisgruntledGoat's comment - after removing Sanctum, remove its config file at `config/sanctum.php` as it will try to import Sanctum's classes and cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.
Even I deleted migration folder, I tried `php artisan migrate:fresh, php artisan migrate:refresh` commands and system tried to create double personal_access_tokens_table.

```
2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table
2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table_2
```

I uninstalled Sanctum and installed again.
Problem solved.
Now migration works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#migration-customization), I applied these changes on the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class, which worked for me. By default, these two package migration is set to true. You will have to ignore this.

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        //Ignore default migration from here
        Sanctum::ignoreMigrations();
        Telescope::ignoreMigrations();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As the error indicates, the table exists.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
./composer dump-autoload
```

Will not work. Why? Because laravel checks against the `migration` table and not the cache or config.

Amongst the solutions, you have:

1. `artisan migrate:fresh` which will [drop all tables from the database and then execute the migrate command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)
2. In the `migrations` table, manually delete the record for the migration. And delete the instance of the table.

The screenshot you have shared is from the code, not the database. If you refer to the database, you will find a record with that name.

**Why does this happen?**

Migrations run in batches. When a migration file is deleted after the table is created, the table will still exist. The appropriate way is to rollback that migration. As such, just because the file does not exist,  doesn't mean the table doesn't exist.